# Laravel 5.2 use custom Controller Trait

Tags: namespaces, laravel-5, traits

I want to use my custom `Trait` stored in `app` directory into my controller. However I always get this message:

> Trait 'app\MessageTrait' not found

**My Controller:**

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use app\Http\Requests;
use app\User;
use app\MessageTrait;

class login extends Controller{
    use MessageTrait;
    public function index(Request $request){
        return back();
    }
}
```

My `MessageTrait` is contained within `MessageTrait.php`, located in app directory. Code looks like this:

**My Trait:**

```
trait MessageTrait{
    public function success(){
        return 'success';
    }
    public function error($message){
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

First I thought it may be a `Namespace` issue - however, `User` class could be found using same namespacing as my `MessageTrait`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `namespace app` to the top line of my Trait file. Everything works as expected now!